# Finding all unique paths in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph

I have a problem where I need to search for **all** unique paths in an undirected graph of degree <=4. The graph is basically a grid, and all connections are between direct neighbors only (4-way).

- A path cannot visit the same vertex
  more than once.
- A path can visit any
  number of vertices to make a path.
- A path contains at least 2 vertices.

How do I go about this problem?

[image]

Comment: I can't understand the meaning of unique path, buy your definition I think there are at most 4*n unique path, each path is one edge.

Comment: I believe the graph is connected (all vertices can be reached)

Comment: @Saeed I think the requirement that a path cannot visit the same vertex more than once simply means that the path cannot contain any cycles.

Comment: @Joel, This is a `simple path` definition in all graph references (i.e see wiki), but I don't know what's the meaning of unique? finding simple paths in graph, is simple backtracking but if the OP wants anything else I want to know about it.

Comment: @hyn, As you know, number of Shortest Paths (a kind of simple paths) in grid of size n*n is (1/n+1) * C(n,2n) [Catalan Number] so each algorithm you using for finding them, is NP-Compelete, but if you want to find number of them, or unique path has special meaning, may be there is another way, but in the case of finding all simple paths, I think it's easy enough with backtracking (and it's just theory because your algorithm can not work for 50*50 grid), and it's better do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the pseudocode I just came up with:

1. Start at any node.
2. Get all of its paths
3. See where they lead, if it's a node that has not been visited then visit it.
4. Call the same function recursively for the nodes from the previous paths.
5. Keep a counter for the number of paths.

This would be this code in Java (untested):

```
public int getPaths (Node n, Set<Node> nodesVisited) {
    int pathCount = 0;
    for (Path p : n.getPaths()) {
        Node otherSide = p.getOtherNode(n); // Where this function basically takes a node and gets the other node in the path
        if (!(nodesVisited.contains(otherSide))) {
            nodesVisited.add(otherSide);
            pathCount += 1 + getPaths(otherSide, new Set<Nodes>(nodesVisited));
        }
    }
    return pathCount;
}
```

This should find the paths from one starting node. You can start it on each node but you'd get some duplicates. To weed them out you'd also need to return the paths though.

Comment: Confirmed to work, even though I need to find ways to speed this up quite a bit..

Comment: Would love to see an answer with a PriorityQueue implementation.  Recursion is extremely inefficient when the number of vertices get in the high 10^n area.